# laravel - insert in one table, update in another

Tags: database, laravel, methods, sql-update

I have a method (store) that adds an entry in a specific table.

In the user table, I have a counter associated with the user. Each time the Store method above is executed, I need to count down one on the user counter column for the active user.

```
auth()->user()->licnr;
```

What would be the proper way of doing this in laravel?

I would create a method in the home controller, called for example "countdown" and then from inside the store method call it. But I am not sure that this is the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new **static** method and then call it when you use the store method as you said, i think this is the correct way to go, given the [Single-responsability principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

> The single-responsibility principle is a computer-programming principle that states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class, module or function. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as, "A class should have only one reason to change," although, because of confusion around the word "reason" he more recently stated "This principle is about people."

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196929/can-should-the-single-responsibility-principle-be-applied-to-new-code) is a great example of this principle